# asm8086 - maze game project

Tags: assembly, project, emulation, maze

I'm doing a project for school and we have to use asm8086 with the emu program.
I chose my project to be couple of mazes.
In some levels, I want the player to have an easier way to finish the maze. I had and idea to program some kind of 'teleport' that when you walk with your character into it you get teleported to a closer point in the end of that maze. Here is what I mean:

```
track3    db        "_______________________________" 
      db 10,13,"| |    |  |  |       |Z       |"
      db 10,13,"| | *| |  |  |  *| * | *|**|* |" 
      db 10,13,"| |  | |  |  |*  |*  |  |  |  |" 
      db 10,13,"| |  | |  |  | * |   |* |  | *|" 
      db 10,13,"| |  | |  |  |   |  *|  |  |  |" 
      db 10,13,"| |* | |  |  |* *|*  | *|  |- |" 
      db 10,13,"| |  | |  |  |   |  *|  |__|  |" 
      db 10,13,"| |  |    |  | * | * |* |     |" 
      db 10,13,"| |  | | O|  |  *|      |  |--|" 
      db 10,13,"| | *| | *|  |*  |***|**|- |*¯ " 
      db 10,13,"| |  | |  |  |       |  |  |  |" 
      db 10,13,"| |  |*|  |  |   |   |  | *| *|" 
      db 10,13,"| |  |    | *|***|   |  |  |  |"
      db 10,13,"| |* | |**|*         |  | -|* |"
      db 10,13,"|    * |     |   |   |  |     |"
      db 10,13,"|-----------------------------|$"
```

- '>>' is the end current maze and the start of the next one.
- Ignore '*'.

What I want to do is when you walk into the 'O' you will get teleported to 'Z', and I need help to write that code.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't expect to much help without showing some code you've written.

Comment: It's a bit unclear exactly what you're having trouble with. I assume that you're keeping track of the player's current position on the map. So if the current position contains `'O'`, change the player's position to the position of the `'Z'` (which you could either hardcode, or find by searching through the map).